# WPF (Image scroller)

Tags: wpf, imagebrush

I am working in WPF to create Image scroller. I set an background image to a grid using image brush. While scrolling an image it flicker a lot. Any solution for that?

Code:

Xaml:

```
<Grid Name="ImageGrid">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="imagebrush"
                Stretch="Fill" TileMode="Tile"
                ViewportUnits="Absolute"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard HandoffBehavior="Compose">
                <Storyboard>
                    <RectAnimation x:Name="myRectAnimation"   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Viewport" 
                               RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind

```
imagebrush = new ImageBrush();
imagebrush.ImageSource = bmp;

imagebrush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;

imagebrush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 1024, this.Height);
imagebrush.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;


RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(ImageGrid.Background, EdgeMode.Aliased);

ImageGrid.Height = height;
ImageGrid.Width = width;
ImageGrid.Background = imagebrush;

myRectAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(scrollspeed);

myRectAnimation.To = new Rect(-1024, 0, 1024, this.Height);
```

Comment: Any code to see the issue?

Comment: You need to share the code as well in order for us to be able to help you

Comment: I have share the code.